# Is it possible to groups class under one parent class for consistency?

Tags: css, sass

I'm working with Tailwind css, which is really good because of those utility classes. Even Bootstrap has many utility classes. a single element can have so many utility classes.

```
<div class="sm:col-span-6 flex flex-col flex-auto p-6 bg-card shadow rounded-2xl max-h-96">
</div>
```

Is it possible to group those classes in one super class and only apply the one?

```
.wrapper {
 class1;
 class3;
 class3;
 ...
 classn;
```

}

And apply that on the HTML element

```
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible. However, is there anything close to this?

Thank for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using tailwind's components and `@apply`. More on that [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply).

In your tailwind setup file:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .wrapper {
    @apply sm:col-span-6 flex flex-col flex-auto p-6 bg-card shadow rounded-2xl max-h-96;
  }
}
```

You would then be able to use it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">...</div>
```

Comment: Great! Is there something similar that I can use with bootstrap, because it has now so many utility classes too.

Comment: @Richard77 I am not a Bootstrap user, and can't answer that for you.

Comment: Depending on how you are using bootstrap, but in scss you can do something like: `.wrapper { @extend .d-flex;}`